# Dynamic MatLab data update from MEX file

Tags: c++, matlab

I want to connect MatLab to a dynamic data source. The data source only has a C++ API.  I am somewhat familiar with MEX files which are dynamic libraries that expose functions to Matlab.

Is there a way to push data dynamically from a thread running in my MEX file back to MatLab? I understand I could poll from MatLab but am interested if there's a way to automatically update a value in a MatLab array from within a thread running in the context of the MEX file.

Comment: MATLAB is not a real time programing language, so you can't do that. The closest would be writing a loop in matlab that starts by updating the variables.

Comment: *Techincally* there is a way, but it is “illegal”, and will cause huge problems in your code because it breaks standard MATLAB expectations. I’m short, you could write to a MATLAB array from the MEX-file, updating its values (not growing the array). MATLAB’s lazy copying mechanism will make it hard to work with this “magically changing” array though. I would not attempt this.

Comment: So yes, @AnderBiguri is right for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - thanks. Looks like I will stick to polling the array.